# True or False output to column

Tags: csv, powershell

I use this script to import the csv file and modify it and then export it
I want to read the data in column 'Member of' and if string '[Admin...whatever string...]' found, output in column 'Admin Priviledges' should be TRUE else FALSE.

I try with boolean like below:

```
Import-Csv csvdatacol.csv |
  Select-Object Name, Hostname, 'Last Logon Date', 'Member of',
                @{n='Admin Priviledges';e={[bool]()}}
```

Comment: `[bool]($_.'Member of' -like Admin*)`

Comment: thankyou, I modified it with ''
e={[boolean]($_.'Member of' -like 'Administrators*' )}}
still I got False for all entries and I need [Admin* as string

Comment: You may also need to handle cases where "Administrators" is not the first group in the list. Your question would've been clearer had you just added the code to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38504420/1630171) instead of deleting it.

Comment: to Ansgar, I thought that I had to rebuild the question, that is why I deleted it, as you can see I'm new user, I don't know what is ok...
if admin is presented it will be after [ and I don't care about the rest of the string. [ bracket is regexp, I need it as text but then * is regexp as well and I need it as regexp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this in the expression for the field "Admin Privileges":

```
@($_.'Member Of' -replace '^\[|\]$' -split ',') -contains 'Administrators'
```

Comment: it works!thank you! I cannot understand where we declare the true or false?

Comment: The operation `array -contains value` returns a boolean value `$true` or `$false` which becomes `True` or `False` respectively when cast to a string.